# Syntax error when doing an update to modify multiple fields using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Can I modify the mysql syntax SET more of a sample script:

```
UPDATE login SET id='21' AND ip='789' WHERE nama='ariel'
```

Please corrected if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should use `AND` like that. Instead I think it should be something more like a list like this:

```
UPDATE login SET id='21',ip='789' WHERE nama='ariel'
```

`AND` is typically used as part of a `WHERE` clause, not in the list of fields to be updated.

Comment: I managed with the syntax:
UPDATE login SET id = '21 ', ip = '789' WHERE name = 'ariel'
Thank you for your help a lot.

Comment: AND can be part of the set portion. `update x set y=1 and 2` is perfectly valid syntax, though not particularly useful.

Answer (score 6):

`And` should be `,`

```
UPDATE login SET id='21', ip='789' WHERE nama='ariel'
```